# Create a new table in snowflake from pandas df in python

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to create a new table in snowflake from a pandas df in python, but it gives me an error : *“No Active warehouse selected in the current session. Select an active warehouse with the ‘use warehouse’ command”* but I do not see where I can add that command.

I connected to Snowflake using SQLAlchemy

```
account_identifier = '<account_identifier>'
user = '<user_login_name>'
password = '<password>'
database_name = '<database_name>'
schema_name = '<schema_name>'


conn_string = f"snowflake://{user}:{password}@{account_identifier}/{database_name}/{schema_name}"
engine = create_engine(conn_string)
```

then I tried to create my table using

```
with engine.connect() as con:
        df.to_sql(name=table_name.lower(), con=con, if_exists=if_exists, method=pd_writer)
```

it gave me the error *“No Active warehouse selected in the current session. Select an active warehouse with the ‘use warehouse’ command” *. It created the new table in snowflake but without any data.

Comment: Does the solution I proposed work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use warehouse_name while connecting to snowflake.

```
account_identifier = '<account_identifier>'
user = '<user_login_name>'
password = '<password>'
database_name = '<database_name>'
schema_name = '<schema_name>'
warehouse_name = '<warehouse_name>'

conn_string = f"snowflake://{user}:{password}@{account_identifier}/{database_name}/{schema_name}/?warehouse={warehouse_name}"
engine = create_engine(conn_string)
```